# How to removed ripples cause by zero-padding in fft?

Tags: matlab, fft, window-functions

**Desired outcome:** Interpolation in frequency domain

**Attempts:** Zero padding when doing fft

**Problem:** Ripples in frequency domain appeared after fft with zero padding

**Code to reproduce the problem:**

```
L0 = 1024;
t = linspace(-10*pi,10*pi,L0);
yt = sin(t)+cos(2*t)+0.1*randi(10,[1 L0]);

for i = 0:4
    mul = 2^i;                                 %zero padding multiplier
    L = L0*mul;                                 
    T0 = (max(t)-min(t))/(L-1);                %period
    f = (0:L/2)/T0/L;                          %frequency axis                         
    
    yc = fft(yt,L)/L;
    yc = yc(1:L/2+1);
    
    figure
    plot(f,abs(yc));
end
```

**Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windowing the time domain function prior to zero padding will reduce the ripples caused by zero padding (due to the otherwise sharp truncation of the time domain function). Without additional windowing you are equivalently multiplying your longer time domain function with a rectangular window, which Fourier Transform is a Sinc function. To reproduce this exactly in frequency the frequency must extend to infinity, which is doesn't in the discrete system so aliasing of these tails in frequency occurs, resulting in ripple. Choose a window whose Fourier Transform has tails that are much lower at the aliasing frequencies and the ripple will be significantly reduced! (I personally like the Kaiser window as you can adjust the trade between width of the main lobe (frequency resolution) and depth of the tails (dynamic range) by adjusting the Beta factor in the window construction.

Comment: after applying kaiser window: yc = fft(kaiser(L,0.5).*yt,L)/L; the data just have a line at f=0 regardless of the beta factor.

Comment: @7E10FC9A That is simply the mean value of your signal (the dc term). If you don't want that, subtract the mean after windowing.

Comment: It turns out karser return a column vector, while yt is a row vector (blame the linspace), which is the cause of the problem. Is there a way to estimate beta factor according to NFFT and zero padding factor ?

Comment: review the Fourier Transform of the window which will show you directly the frequency domain characteristics---- easy way is to zero pad the window and take the FFT of that. You will see the trade directly of main-lobe width (meaning reduced resolution) and side-lobe suppression (reduced ripple)

Answer (score 0):

A finite length sequence actually implies a rectangular window $w[n]$ on it, so you actually have :

$$ x[n] = w[n]\cdot x_i[n] \tag{1}$$
where $w[n]$ equals zero when $n<0$ or $n>M$, $x_i[n]$ is the ideal sequence defined on entire $-\infty < n <\infty$. It may have infinite support, or still finite though.

When you compute the DTFT of $x[n]$ therefore you will have :

$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} X_i(e^{j\omega}) \star W(e^{j\omega}) \tag{2} $$

where, $X_i(e^{j\omega})$ is the DTFT of the ideal sequence and $W(e^{j\omega})$ is the DTFT of the window sequence, and $\star$ denotes convolution (of the periodic functions). This results in

$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} X_i(e^{j\theta})\cdot W(e^{j(\omega-\theta)}) d\theta \tag{3}$$

Now for a rectangular window of length $M+1$ the associated DTFT will be :

$$W(e^{j\omega}) =  e^{-j \omega M/2} \cdot \frac{\sin( \frac{\omega}{2}(M+1))}{\sin( \frac{\omega}{2})} \tag{4} $$

something called a Dirichlet Kernel (or a periodic **sinc**) function.

In this case your ideal sequence is a sine/cosine wave which is :
$$x_i[n] = \cos(\omega_0 n) \tag{5}$$

Where its DTFT will be :
$$X_i(e^{j\omega}) = \pi \delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \pi \delta(\omega + \omega_0)  \tag{6} $$

which is periodic in $\omega$ with $2\pi$ and $\delta()$ is the continuous Dirac impulse.

If you carry out the convolution you will see that your signal spectrum is :

$$X(e^{j \omega}) = 0.5 ~W(e^{j (\omega- \omega_0)}) + 0.5 ~W(e^{j (\omega + \omega_0)}) \tag{7} $$

Hence what you are observing as the spectrum (for an ideal sine wave) is the spectrum of the window function. The rectangular window has quite strong ripples and you see them when you interpolate suffieciently by zero padding before FFT.

If you use more proper windows such as Hamming, Blackman,or Kaiser, which taper to zero at their tails, then those ripples will be invisible (but still there).